# How to mount a radial inductor?

Tags: inductor, pcb-assembly

I've just received an answer to a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310275/extent-of-ground-plane-beneath-filtered-dc-converter) that's resulted in re selecting an inductor.  So I'll be using something like this:-

[image: radial inductor]

(It's from [here](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/leaded-inductors/1048436/)). How are these mounted?  There's only two wires which lie in a plane therefore the component will rock or swing and the leads quickly fracture.  Is this a case for kludging it on with lots of hot glue?

Comment: Once soldered down they swing quite a bit less than you'd think.

Comment: Don't accidentally devise a mounting scheme that acts as a shorted turn. Apart from that I have no useful advice.

Comment: THe most popular material for adhesive is a certain brand of white Polyurethane but you can just use the stuff at Home Depot in the long tubes. (inexpensive, low leakage, stiff but not brittle, excellent adhesion. yet repairable.)

Comment: What is a "radial inductor"? Do you mean toroidal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some more details to what Nick Alexeev has told you in his good answer, you may find additional information on toroid mounting in [this document ("Effective Mounting of Toroidal Cores", by Richard Barden; Lodestone Pacific)](http://www.lodestonepacific.com/Toroid.pdf).

Excerpts (emphasis mine):

> The toroids can be attached to the mount with either adhesives or mechanical
>   means. Cup shaped toroid mounts can be filled with a potting or encapsulation
>   compound to both adhere and protect the wound toroid. **Horizontal mounting
>   offers both a low profile and a low center of gravity in applications that will experience shock and vibration.** As the toroid’s diameter gets larger, horizontal mounting begins to use up valuable circuit board real estate. **If there is room in the enclosure, vertical mounting is used to save board space.**
>
> [...]
>
> [image]
>
> The leads from the toroidal winding are attached to the mount’s terminals, usually by soldering as shown in Figure
>   6. If the winding’s wire is large and stiff enough, the wire can be “self leaded” and positioned through the header or
>   mount into the printed circuit board, as in Figures 3, 7 and 8. The advantage of self leading mounts is that the expense and vulnerability of an additional intermediate solder connection is avoided. **The toroids can be attached to the mount with either adhesives, mechanical means or by encapsulation**. Cup shaped toroid mounts, (Figures 8, 9 and 10) can be filled with a potting or encapsulation compound to both adhere and protect the wound toroid. Vertical mounting saves circuit board real estate when a toroid’s diameter gets larger, but creates a component height
>   issue. **Vertical mounting also raises the component’s center of gravity making it vulnerable to shock and vibration**.

Comment: Why no one mentions a simple flat horizontal mounting, either by a  hot glue, or by a screw in the center? Unwind half a turn, and put it flat on PCB, it will be mucho solid mechanically.

Comment: @AliChen Horizontal mounting *is* mentioned in the document I linked to. I'll add some more excerpts. There are tradeoffs between the two approaches.

Comment: I did't bother to read the link, just looking at posted pictures... I think you need to incorporate a picture like this one, http://my.rs-online.com/web/p/leaded-inductors/8711367/

Comment: This is also a good one, http://hifonics.com.s43232.gridserver.com/images/product/zeus_amplifiers/zeus_amplifier_spc_coil.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Radial toroids can be mounted in a plastic support
[image] ([source of the photo](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/triad-magnetics/FIT80-1/237-1196-ND/242608))

Radial toroids can be glued directly to the PCB
[image] ([source of the photo](https://www.alliedcomponents.com/product_index.php))

Comment: A quickie...  Original OP had two of these.  Is it acceptable (noise wise) to mount two of these together co-axially?  I mean side by side.  Something I read on a valve amp forum suggested transformers /inductors had to be mounted a right angles so that their  magnetic fields weren't co-incident.  But then they also suggest oxygen free wiring to reduce sonic smearing...

Comment: @PaulUszak Sounds like a good new question.